# Nine Patch Image in Android Game

Tags: android

I am trying to use a nine patch image as a background in an android game. The image expands well in multiple resolutions but, my game has slowed down by 10 fps. I used to get a consistent 45 to 50 fps now I get 35 fps.

The question is when we use a nine patch as a drawable and set it as a background in a view does it have any performance implications as opposed to a plain bitmap drawing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is when we use a nine
>   patch as a drawable and set it as a
>   background in a view does it have any
>   performance implications as opposed to
>   a plain bitmap drawing.

If you are causing it to be stretched, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know why there is a performance drop ? Does the framework do the stretch and draw for every frame ? is this a bug or designed that way ? I hate to increase the app size by dropping in same images in different folders to support multiple resolutions.

Comment: "Do you know why there is a performance drop?" Because stretching isn't free. "Does the framework do the stretch and draw for every frame?" I have no way to answer this, since I am not you, and therefore I did not write your code that is applying the nine-patch.   "is this a bug or designed that way?" I am fairly certain that nine-patch images are not designed with games in mind. They are designed for use as backgrounds of `Button` and `EditText` widgets, not to be drawn on a `Canvas` or whatever it is that you are doing.

Comment: "I hate to increase the app size by dropping in same images in different folders to support multiple resolutions." Nine-patch graphics are not meant to solve the problem of multiple resolutions. Nine-patch graphics are meant to solve the problem of widget backgrounds, which can have arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply.Bottom line : nine patches are not for game backgrounds or to support multiple resolutions.I have no other choice but to use different images for different resolutions.

Comment: @wysiwyg: For games, yes. This is just another one of those places, as with memory allocations, where a game developer has to make sacrifices in the interests of fps. Other developers less constrained by this need don't have the same sorts of challenges. Sorry!